# How can I center a polygon and a path inside <svg>-Tag?

Tags: html, css, svg

How can I center a polygon and a path inside `<svg>`-Tag? I tried using `x` and `y` attributes but this doesn't work. I want the play and pause icon to be centered inside the gray circle.

```css
svg#play {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  fill: white;
  height: calc(70px * 2 - 5px);
  width: calc(70px * 2 - 5px);
}

svg#pause {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  fill: white;
  height: calc(70px * 2 - 5px);
  width: calc(70px * 2 - 5px);
}
```

```html
<svg id="play" class="icon">
<polygon points="9.33 6.69 9.33 19.39 19.3 13.04 9.33 6.69" transform="scale(4.0)"></polygon>
</svg>
<svg id="pause" class="icon">
<path id="ytp-12" d="M 11 10 L 17 10 L 17 26 L 11 26 M 20 10 L 26 10 L 26 26 L 20 26" transform="scale(4.0)"></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add translate values to the transform to move things around till you're happy with the position.

```css
svg#play {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  fill: white;
  height: calc(70px * 2 - 5px);
  width: calc(70px * 2 - 5px);
}

svg#pause {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  fill: white;
  height: calc(70px * 2 - 5px);
  width: calc(70px * 2 - 5px);
}
```

```html
<svg id="play" class="icon">
<polygon points="9.33 6.69 9.33 19.39 19.3 13.04 9.33 6.69" transform="scale(4.0) translate(4, 4)"></polygon>
</svg>
<svg id="pause" class="icon">
<path id="ytp-12" d="M 11 10 L 17 10 L 17 26 L 11 26 M 20 10 L 26 10 L 26 26 L 20 26" transform="scale(4.0) translate(-1.5, -1)"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Will it be better to wrap the SVG around a container and center it with CSS? Would that be a definite solution instead of _playing_ with the values.

Comment: The paths are not centred within the SVG container so while you could move them with a CSS transform you'd still be adjusting the values to suit.

Comment: "..you'd still be adjusting the values to suit": This is a very painful solution to what (in my poorly informed opinion) should have a simple centering option!